# Не работает find для вектора C++

Tags: c++, vector, find

Пишу скриптик сейчас интересный, завис на теме, где надо открыть файл (открыл), прочитать его и записать, в данном случае в вектор (сделал), а вот воспользоваться методом find не могу, надо найти слово "Processor" в получившемся векторе, вроде составил равенство с новой переменной, которая должна указывать равняться результату find, когда пытаюсь вывести через cout (проверить, нашло ли) летит ошибка C2679 Бинарный "<<": не найден оператор...
Вот код, прошу поддержки:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void show_vector(vector<char>& a)
{
    for (auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    ifstream dsdtF("./files/dsdt.dsl", ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
    if (dsdtF.is_open()) {
        cout << "File opened successfully!\n";
        const ifstream::pos_type file_size = dsdtF.tellg();
        vector<char> dsdtVector(file_size);
        dsdtF.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        dsdtF.read(&dsdtVector[0], file_size);
        char toFind[] = "Processor";
        auto pos = find(dsdtVector.begin(), dsdtVector.end(), toFind[0]);
        cout << pos;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Failed to open the file!\n";
    }
    dsdtF.close();
    cin >> x;



    cout << "\n\n\nPress any key to exit...\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: №1. Зачем в вектор символов? Лучше  в строковой объект std::string; №2. Зачем пройтись по   файлу, чтобы знать его размер? Лучше просто добавлять в конец вектора. №3. Вы пытаетесь найти первую букву слова, а не слово...

Comment: №1 и 2 объясню просто: код не мой, я в целом разобрался, по какому принципу он работает, но взят он как раз таки со StackOverflow, поэтому за такие вещи я не ручаюсь) А вот насчет третьего вопроса я уже увидел, почитайте пожалуйста мой последний ответ Harry, там я написал, почему так коряво сделал и ищу в итоге первую букву, взял кусок кода, в котором сперва не разобрался - итог, потянул этот кусок за собой все...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вывести итератор.

Если хотите вывести позицию найденной **буквы `P`**, то выводите

```
cout << distance(dsdtVector.begin(),pos);
```

P.S. Я бы рекомендовал

```
    string dsdtVector(file_size,' ');
    dsdtF.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    dsdtF.read(dsdtVector.data(), file_size);
    char toFind[] = "Processor";
    auto pos = dsdtVector.find(toFind);
    cout << pos;
```

Comment: а что в таком случае возвращает мне метод find?

Comment: Как я и написал - *итератор*, указывающий на найденный элемент. Или `dsdtVector.end()`, если не найден.

Comment: я заметил вы выделили слово "Буква" в оригинальном комментарии, а как найти слово целиком, я читал, что в методе find тип данных искомого должен совпадать с типом данных элемента, в котором производится поиск, как в таком случае надо переделать код чтобы искать именно слово "Processor" целиком? Спасибо за помощь

Comment: См. P.S. в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно в контейнере(в данном случаи вектор) символов, найти последовательность символов(искомое слово). Для этого есть алгоритм `std::search`. В данном случаи вы можете воспользоваться им так:

```
auto It = std::search(dsdtVector.begin(), dsdtVector.end(),
                      toFind, toFind + strlen(toFind) );
if (It == dsdtVector.end())
    cout << "не найдено";
else
    cout << It - dsdtVector.begin();
```

Но проще читать в объект std::string(можете сразу читать по строкам), а потом найти слово его же методом  `std::string::find_first_of`